# Knowing which directory python code uses on a cluster

Tags: python, mpi, mpich

I am working on a cluster with a version of MPICH (MPI).  Basically, the code is run with 1 MPI process on each node, and each process has all of the cores available to it.  This way, there is one MPI process per node that deals with receiving data, then the native multiprocessing for python does some work.

From each node, the data is saved to a directory, this is just as `/myfolder` and they are all saved on the luster file system in the same location.

Now when developing locally, the multiprocessing I am doing uses read/write to memory, and in Linux this basically uses a tmp directory.

```
fd = os.open(filename, os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC | os.O_RDWR)
#Make sure the memory is allocated
assert os.write(fd, '\x00' * memsize) == memsize
#Map the file to memory
buf = mmap.mmap(fd, memsize, mmap.MAP_SHARED,access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
#Put the data
buf.seek(0)
buf.write(data)
buf.seek(0)
buf.close()
os.close(fd)
```

How can I figure out where the tmp is being stored?  For example, I want to make sure it is locally in memory and not on the root node or on the luster system.

The motivation for the question is because the code is working for 10 nodes, but when scaled up to 50 it will hang, with a few of the nodes having started computation and other not starting.  I am wondering if the ones starting have filled the memory of some common machine, causing a crash.

Answer (score 0):

mmap on a parallel file system is possible but almost always a bad idea.  mmap() will do i/o in 4k chunks (linux page size), which may or may not be a good fit for your file system.

You might want to look at mpi4py and its quite good MPI-IO support.   You will be able to avoid the mmap entirely and when you (collectively, if it fits your application's need) write in parallel to your lustre file system, there's a good chance the MPI library will optimize the request for you.